# Grails - Apache Tika plugin test-app failure

Tags: unit-testing, grails, apache-tika

I'm learning how to use the `Apache Tika plugin`. I've just copied the code from [github](https://github.com/dewarim/tikaParser/blob/master/test/unit/tikaParser/TikaServiceSpec.groovy) and I get failure error when unit testing.

This is the `unit test`

```
import grails.test.mixin.TestFor
import spock.lang.Specification

/**
 * Test for tikaService: try to parse test data.
 */
@TestFor(TikaService)
class TikaServiceSpec extends Specification {

    def 'Parse a word file to XML'() {
        given:
        def file = new File('parserTest.doc')

        when:
        def xml = service.parseFile(file)

        then:
        def doc = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)
        doc.body.p.find{
            it.text() == 'This is a simple test document'
        }
    }
}
```

This is the error I get.

```
Running 5 unit tests... 8 of 8
| Failure:  Parse a word file to XML(com.myApp.TikaServiceSpec)
|  Condition not satisfied:
doc.body.p.find{ it.text() == 'This is a simple test document' }
|   |    | |
|   |    | groovy.util.slurpersupport.NoChildren@4c2a4e84
|   |    Tika Parser Test
|   |    This is a simple test document
|   Tika Parser Test
|   This is a simple test document
Tika Parser Test
This is a simple test document
    at com.myApp.TikaServiceSpec.Parse a word file to XML(TikaServiceSpec.groovy:21)
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
dependencies {
    compile('org.apache.tika:tika-core:0.7')
    compile('org.apache.tika:tika-parsers:0.7') { excludes "xercesImpl", "xmlParserAPIs", "xml-apis", "log4j" }
}
```

Comment: You're using massively ancient versions of Apache Tika for a start! What happens if you upgrade to the most recent version, currently 1.12?

Comment: @Gagravarr I've found only 1.11: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tika/tika-core . Where did you find 1.12?

Comment: It's [on the main Maven Central repo servers](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/tika/tika-core/1.12/), I think you must've found a broken mirror :/

Comment: Oh, wow, thanks @Gagravarr. I was following another tutorial and version 1.9 kept giving me the error so I just kept 0.7. I used 1.12 and the unit test works! Also, is there any tutorial site for Tika plugin I can study step by step?

Comment: No idea, sorry, I'm not a grails person. Plenty of Java examples out there, but I don't know how much use they'd be

Comment: @Gagravarr Thanks. Let me ask you one more question. My project's main purpose is to get the uploaded documents (mostly in word docs and pdfs), parse the content, extract and compare certain words/phrases with database, and display the content in an appropriate table cell. Do you think using Tika is a good idea? Is there any better/simpler way?

Comment: Tika is by far the simplest option. Others might be "better", depending on the fidelity of the rendering you want, but likely will be a lot more work and/or cost...

Comment: @Gagravarr Thank you. I really appreciate you taking the time to answer my questions. "Don't" worry, I won't "panic".

Comment: As this is solved, best practice is for you to write up your fix as an answer, so others coming across the question can quickly see what it took to solve it. [See here in the help for details](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Gagravarr, the problem has been solved. I used the version 1.12 and it worked.

The repo is https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/tika/